# neovim sluggish on WSL

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I'm using Linux at home and have to use Windows at work.

In order to simplify my life, I've installed Ubuntu on Windows using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) 2. It's great, with the terminal and all the apps I'm used to.

However, it seems rather sluggish, to the point that even neovim is slow; e.g. deleting a line from a buffer with 100 lines takes a noticable amount of time (just under a second I guess).

**Is this expected?**

**If no, what can I do for troubleshooting?**

**If yes, are there faster alternatives?**

Many thanks

Comment: There is a known bug ([link](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4498)) when using `/mnt/*` folders. If this is your case, try using the `/home/username` folder.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone passing by:

I was using Windows Terminal to interact with WSL2 ubuntu. I changed it to using Alacritty, and now it's *much* better.

Answer (score 0):

I had the following clipboard functionality enabled in my config file:

> opt.clipboard = "unnamedplus"

Removing it and using the default clipboard behaviour fixed by problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).